# Mysql join query with where condition and distinct records

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables called `tc_revenue` and `tc_rates`.

- `tc_revenue` contains :- code, revenue, startDate, endDate
- `tc_rate` contains :- code, tier, payout, startDate, endDate

Now I need to get records where code = 100 and records should be unique..

I have used this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM task_code_rates 
LEFT JOIN task_code_revenue ON task_code_revenue.code = task_code_rates.code
WHERE task_code_rates.code = 105;
```

But I am getting repeated records help me to find the correct solution.

eg:

[image]

in this example every record is repeated 2 time

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "and the records should be distinct"?  Please edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: distinct mean unique . I have 5 records with code = 100.in 1st table and in second table i have only 2.  uniqueness will be based on start date

Comment: . . *sample data*.  That is how you convey what you really mean.

Comment: If you want to fetch all the columns then I think it is unique by itself so it returns all the records, Please post data for more clarity and try at least to post data from both tables where code = 100

Answer (score 0):

Use a group by for whatever field you need unique. For example, if you want one row per code, then:

```
SELECT * FROM task_code_rates LEFT JOIN task_code_revenue ON task_code_revenue.code = task_code_rates.code
where task_code_rates.code = 105
group by task_code_revenue.code, task_code_revenue.tier
```

Comment: But this will return only one record. I have 5 records with code = 100.in 1st table and in second table i have only 2.  uniqueness will be based on start date

Comment: I was just giving an example. Choose the combination of fields you need unique. If you want one row per startDate, then use that in the group by.

Comment: can you please help me with query

Comment: Sure, but you need to give us more info. We don't know what you need. Maybe you can give an example of your data, and an example of what the correct answer looks like. Edit the main question so everyone can easily know what you want.

Comment: You still haven't told us which columns you need to have unique. But I made my best guess, and updated the query.

Answer (score 0):

If code admits duplicates in both tables and you perform join only using code, then you will get the cartessian product between all matching rows from one table and all matching rows from the other.

If you have 5 records with code 100 in first table and 2 records with code 100 in second table, you'll get 5 times 2 results, all combinations between matching rows from the left and the right.

Unless you have duplicates inside one (or both) tables, all 10 results will differ in colums coming either from one table, the other or both.

But if you were expecting to get two combined rows and three rows from first table with nulls for second table columns, this will not happen.

This is how joins work, and anyway, how should the database decide which rows to combine if it didn't generate all combinations and let you decide in where clause?

Maybe you need to add more criteria to the ON clause, such as also matching dates?